# Убрать имя файла из пути

Tags: delphi

Имеется строка `C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\Текст.txt`

Задача спарсить из этой строки `C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\`, использую функцию Pars

```
Edit2.text := Pars('C:\', Edit1.Text, '\');
```

Но она парсит до первого `\`, т.е до `Users`, а надо чтобы спарсило `C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\`, помогите решить проблему.

```
Edit2.text := Pars('C:\', Edit1.Text, '\');
```

Сама функция:

```
function Pars(T_, ForS, _T: string): string;<br/>
var
  a, b: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (T_ = '') or (ForS = '') or (_T = '') then  Exit;
  a := Pos(T_, ForS);
  if a = 0 then Exit
  else  a := a + Length(T_);
  ForS := Copy(ForS, a, Length(ForS) - a + 1);
  b := Pos(_T, ForS);
  if b > 0 then Result := Copy(ForS, 1, b - 1);
end;
```

Comment: Хорошенько поработай над формулировкой вопроса и поработай над его оформлением.

Comment: Оформление искажается после сохранения. 
Формулировка вопроса понятна

Comment: Добавь минимум по 4 пробела перед каждой строкой кода. А так же копируй вместе с отступами. И поверь на слово, у тебя проблемы с формулировкой вопроса.

Answer (score 9):

Загляните в `SysUtils` возможно Вам чего и приглянется, например, `ExtractFilePath`.